# Proper structure of AJAX handler

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

My .NET project handles AJAX requests.  There are no UI controls at all, it simply responds with text to every AJAX post.

This is my current structure:

```
<%
SynchLock DBNull.Value
  Main
End SynchLock
%>

<script language="VB" runat="Server">

Sub Main
  Dim a() As String = Request.Form("a").Split(" "c)
  ' a: (0) version, (1) config, (2) userid, (3) sessionid, (4) activity

  ' Initializations

  Using conn As DbConnection = sess.Connection
    Select Case a(4)
    Case 0
      ActivityOne
    Case 1
      ActivityTwo
    Case 2
      ActivityThree
    ...
    Case 28
      ActivityTwentyEight
    End Select
  End Using
End Sub

'All the activity functions and lots of other Functions

</script>
```

This works but I think it can be improved; I'm not sure how to proceed.

Some of the activities call subfunctions and I'm looking at breaking some of the activities out even further.  In order to encapsulate all the functionality of an activity, I'm considering changing the activities from functions to classes, like so:

```
Select Case a(4)
Case 0
  Dim a1 As New ActivityOne
  a1.Execute
...
End Select
```

Is this the right approach?  If I proceed with the classes, I have related questions:

(1) Do I code the "New" Sub of the classes or an "Execute" (or some other name) Sub?  If I code the "New" Sub, then I can reduce the above code to:

```
Select Case a(4)
Case 0
  New ActivityOne
...
End Select
```

This seems easier, but are there disadvantages?

(2) The activities all rely on other Request.Form inputs.  Do I (a) pass access the HttpContext.Current object from within the classes or (b) pass the Request object to the activity or (c) pass the specific Request.Form variables needed by the activity?

e.g.

(a) New ActivityOne ' the class accesses HttpContext.Current.Form("b"), etc.

```
Class ActivityOne
  Sub New
    Dim p1 As String = HttpContext.Current.Form("b")
    ...
  End Sub
End Class
```

(b) New ActivityOne(Request)

```
Class ActivityOne
  Sub New(req As HttpRequest)
    Dim p1 As String = req.Form("b")
    ...
  End Sub
End Class
```

(c) New ActivityOne(Request.Form("b"))

```
Class ActivityOne
  Sub New(p1 As String)
    ...
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET file?

Comment: You shouldn't be using ASPX files for this then. Use HTTPHandlers.

Comment: @Phill - Thanks, I'll look into HTTPHandlers

Comment: @Phill - That was truly **great** advice about the HTTPHandlers... you should add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use ASPX pages for AJAX requests. Just use an HTTPHandler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

> The activities all rely on other Request.Form inputs. Do I (a) pass access the HttpContext.Current object from within the classes or (b) pass the Request object to the activity or (c) pass the specific Request.Form variables needed by the activity?

You could just pass the Request.Form NameValue collection.

Also, since you're using ASP.NET, you could consider using an ASP.NET AJAX enabled webservice [click](http://www.semenoff.dk/en/Code-Corner/ASP.Net.AJAX/WebService-From-JavaScript.aspx) and make methods for each of your activities.  This would simplify your code.  You could also make a WCF REST service and call it with jQuery.

You don't need to be picking out querystring values or creating massive switch statements.  ASP.NET has the infrastructure in place to handle this sort of thing.

Comment: I like your idea about passing the Request.Form NameValue collection.  I don't think I want to use the ASP.NET AJAX enabled webservice.  I'm using the XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript to handle the AJAX and it's working perfectly well.